# is "someString" equivalent to new String("someString")? in java

Tags: java, string, compiler-construction, instantiation, compiler-optimization

I always thought that an expression like this in java:

```
String tmp = "someString";
```

is just some kind of "syntactic sugar" for

```
String tmp = new String("someString");
```

As I recently decompiled my java app, I saw that ALL usages of

```
public static final String SOME_IDENTIFIER = "SOME_VALUE";
```

are replaced in code by just the value and the static final variable is stripped.

Doesn't instantiate this a new String everytime one wants to access the static final? How can this be considered as an "compiler optimization"??

Comment: Most probably the reason of Internity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

String literals in Java source are *interned*, meaning that all literals with the same text will resolve to the same instance.

In other words, `"A" == "A"` will be true.

Creating a new `String` instance will bypass that; `"A" == new String("A")` will not be true.

Comment: But equals() will return true in both cases. (not to confuse beginners)

Answer (score 4):

```
String tmp1 = "someString"; 
String tmp2 = new String("someString");
String tmp3 = "someString"; 

 if(tmp1 == tmp2)/* will return false as both are different objects
                     stored at differnt location in heap */

 if(tmp1.equals(tmp2))/* will return true as it will compare the values 
                        not object reference */

 if(tmp1 == tmp3)/* will return true. see string literals and they are interned. 
                  brief about them is they  are stored in pool in  permgen  till 
                  java 6.They are stored as part of heap only in java 7
                  Every time u create string literal with same value , 
                  it will refer from same location in pool instead of creating 
                  object each time */
```

Comment: Use /* multi-line comments */ :)

Comment: AFAIK the Strings are not stored in permgen anymore (Oracle Java SE 7) and the permgen will be removed altogether in Oracle Java SE 8.

Answer (score 1):

String in Java source are stored in a constants table in the .class file.  When a class file is loaded, all the strings in the constants table are interned; unique strings are converted to object instances.  References to them refer to the interned instance, so additional references don't generate additional objects.